# Proper Approach for Custom URL's with DNN 7.1.2 and Advanced URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I have a dnn 7.1.2 site and I really am liking the new url formats from the advanced mode on the friendly url provider.  However, in my web.config, i have a bunch of url rewrite rules that are were working great with it set to humanFriendly, but now it performs an additional 301 on top of my rewrite, which is not good.

How can I tell DNN to ignore a url that has been rewritten already and just pass it through?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you add the urls you are rewriting in the web.config to the taburls table and remove them from the web.config, letting DNN handle the rewriting instead of doing it with IIS. Should make things easier to follow for DNN upgrades in the future as well

Comment: So with the TabUrl's table, I should be able to add a record for each custom url and what it should rewrite as?  I am having trouble following how that is supposed to work.

Comment: My understanding is that the table would allow you to have customer URLs that all redirect to the URL of the page, doing redirects to the "default" url for that page.

Comment: What if I have many url's pointing to one page with the rewrite simply adding the proper query string?

Comment: I don't know about that one, sorry.